# When I added my widget into the Listview,I got a error

Tags: flutter, dart

The error is

> setState() called in constructor: _journalItemState#76cf3(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not mounted) This happens when you call setState() on a State object for a widget that hasn't been inserted into the widget tree yet. It is not necessary to call setState() in the constructor, since the state is already assumed to be dirty when it is initially created.

If I dont call setState after inserting the data into the List the error will not be caused.But in that case the data won't be shown.
This is my code.

```
import '../Userdata.dart';
import '../normalhttp.dart';
import '../thirdparty/alert.dart';
import 'journalItem.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:Lifer_flutter/normalhttp.dart';

class journalList extends StatefulWidget {
  String jwt;
  String userName;
  journalList (this.jwt,this.userName,{Key key}) :super (key:key);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new RJournalList ();
  }
}
class RJournalList extends State<journalList> {
  LiferLocalizations locale;
  List<String> ids;
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController ();
  int journalReadBegin = 0;
  int oneTimeLoadJournalItemNumber = 10;
  Future<Null> refreshAll () async{
    ids.clear();
    journalReadBegin = 0;
    //return null;
    await insertSeveralJournals();
    return null;
  }
  Future <void> insertSeveralJournals () async{
    Map<String,dynamic> ret = await JsonPost ("/JournalSystem/GetLeastSeveralJournals", {
      "jwt":widget.jwt,
      "ItemNumberStart":journalReadBegin,
      "ItemNumberEnd":journalReadBegin + oneTimeLoadJournalItemNumber,
    });
    if (!ret.containsKey("result") || ret ["result"] == false) {
      networkErrorAlert(context);
      return ;
    }
    List<String> rids = List.from(ret ["payload"]);
    debugPrint ("l:" + rids.length.toString());
    setState(() {
      ids = rids;
    });
    // for (int i = 0;i < rids.length;++ i) {
    //     ids.add (rids [i]);
    //   }
  }
  bool loaded = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    locale = LiferLocalizations.of (context);
    if (!loaded) {
      ids= List ();
      loaded = true;
    }
    CheckJwt().then((res) {
      if (!res) {
        networkErrorAlert(context);
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }
    });
    GetOneTimeLoadJournalItemNumber ().then((num) {
      oneTimeLoadJournalItemNumber = num;
    });
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar (
        title: new Text (locale.yourJournal),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
                //foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
                shape: const CircleBorder(),
                onPressed: () async {
                  Map<String,dynamic> ret = await JsonPost ("/JournalSystem/NewJournal",{
                      "jwt":widget.jwt
                    }
                  );
                  if (ret.containsKey("result") == false) {
                    networkErrorAlert(context);
                    return ;
                  }
                  refreshAll();
        },
      ),
      body:  RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: refreshAll,
          child:
            new ListView.builder(
              itemCount: ids.length,
              itemBuilder: (context,index) {
                debugPrint (ids [index]);
                //return journalItem (widget.jwt,ids [index]);
                debugPrint ("added");
                return journalItem (
                  journalId: ids [index],
                  jwt: widget.jwt,
                  key: GlobalKey ()
                );
              },
              physics: new AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              controller: _scrollController, 
            ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

The error cames out when I called insertSeveralJournals.
The code of journalItem.

```
import 'package:Lifer_flutter/thirdparty/MaterialTapWidget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; 
import 'package:Lifer_flutter/journal/struct.dart';
import 'journalShow.dart';
class journalItem extends StatefulWidget {
  String jwt,journalId;
  journalItem ({this.jwt,this.journalId,Key key}):super(key:key);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _journalItemState (jwt,journalId);
  }
}
class _journalItemState extends State <journalItem> {
  IconData data;
  String journalId,jwt;
  Weather iconId;
  Journal journal;
  _journalItemState (this.jwt,this.journalId) {
    setState ((){
      journal = Journal (context,journalId,jwt,() {
        iconId = journal.weatherIcon;
      });
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
  MaterialTapWidget (
    onTap: () {
      //点击那就进入展示页面。
      MaterialJournalShowWindow (journal);
    },
    child:Padding (
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon (getIconData(iconId)),
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text (
                journal.title,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 50,
                ),
                maxLines: 1,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
              Text (
                journal.content,
                softWrap: true,
                maxLines: 4,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    )
  );
  }
}
```

The debug log .

```
[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
[38;5;244mThe following assertion was thrown building NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification>:[39;49m
setState() called in constructor: _journalItemState#76cf3(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not mounted)


[38;5;248mThis happens when you call setState() on a State object for a widget that hasn't been inserted into the widget tree yet. It is not necessary to call setState() in the constructor, since the state is already assumed to be dirty when it is initially created.[39;49m

[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mListView[39;49m
[38;5;244mWhen the exception was thrown, this was the stack[39;49m
[38;5;244m#0      State.setState.<anonymous closure>[39;49m
[38;5;244m#1      State.setState[39;49m
[38;5;248m#2      new _journalItemState[39;49m
[38;5;248m#3      journalItem.createState[39;49m
[38;5;244m#4      new StatefulElement[39;49m
[38;5;244m...[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 263 pos 16: 'child == null || indexOf(child) > index': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mListView[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
A RenderSliverPadding expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderErrorBox.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mListView[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4022 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mListView[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4022 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mListView[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4022 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mListView[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4022 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mListView[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4022 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mListView[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4022 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mListView[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4022 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mListView[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4022 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mRefreshIndicator[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4022 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mRefreshIndicator[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4022 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mRefreshIndicator[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4022 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mScaffold[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4022 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mScaffold[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4022 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mScaffold[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4022 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mScaffold[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4022 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mScaffold[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4022 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mScaffold[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4022 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mScaffold[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4022 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mScaffold[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4022 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mScaffold[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4022 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mScaffold[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4022 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mScaffold[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4022 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mScaffold[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4022 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mjournalList[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4022 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mjournalList[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your error log response, it was given very clear.

> It is not necessary to call setState() in the constructor, since the state is already assumed to be dirty when it is initially created.

Constructor's are meant to be created, just to hold the objects, passing the data not to handle the functionality or to change the behaviour of your UI. Adding the setState() inside the Constructor is totally a bad approach.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `setState` in constructor of that `State`. Just do

```
_journalItemState (this.jwt,this.journalId) {
  journal = Journal (context,journalId,jwt,() {
    iconId = journal.weatherIcon;
  });
}
```